# VSCode quits when opened

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

My VSCode has been quitting when I open it.  My friend has been having this issue, and his problem is the same as mine.

Heres the VSCode Github issue (all of the logs are the same as mine): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119514

Why does this happen? I'm on Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's worth waiting for one of the developers to respond to the ticket you opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check latest response on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119514). It got something to do with Windows 10 settings